# Unable to delete a document in mongodb using mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete all the documents that have a state equal to off when /ledon occurs and to delete documents which have the state=on when /ledoff routes occurs in mongodb atlas the code is as shown below

I tried using modelname.remove, modelname.deleteMany, but it does not work for me in console it is showing deleted but in mongodb atlas it is not deleting the documents

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const path=require('path')

const data = require('../../models/data')

router.post('/ledon',(req,res)=>{
   const newdata1 = new data({
       state:'ledon'
   })
   newdata1.save()
   .then(console.log('done'))
   .catch(err=>console.log(err))
   data.find({state:'ledoff'})
   .then((isfind)=>{
       if(isfind){
           data.deleteMany({state:'ledoff'}).then(()=>{
               console.log('deleted')
           }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
       }
   })
   .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})

router.post('/ledoff',(req,res)=>{
    const newdata2 = new data({
        state:'ledoff'
    })
    newdata2.save()
    .then(console.log('done'))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    data.find({state:'ledon'})
    .then((isfind)=>{
        if(isfind){
            data.deleteMany({state:'ledon'}).then(()=>{
                console.log('deleted')
            }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
        }
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))

})

module.exports=router
```

it is not deleting the documents in the mongodb atlas but in console it is showing that it is deleting the documents. Can anyone help me with this problem?

my schema design look like this

```
const moongose=require('mongoose')
const schema = moongose.Schema

const data =new schema({
    state:{
        type:String,
        default:true,
        required:true
    }
})

module.exports=databack = moongose.model('buttondata',data)
```

Comment: deleteMany will always show deleted when the query executes, I think it returns how many were deleted in the promise though (so just bind the returned value and print it to confirm). Also, you don't need to 'find' before a delete, just fire the delete at mongo and it'll handle it if there is none. Faster since then you only send 1 query always.

Comment: Also what does data#save() do?

Comment: data.save(). Saves the data to database same as insert() as mongoose does not have inserOne() so i used this method